# Odoo server error after installing custom module doesn't allow to install new modules

Tags: odoo

I just installed a custom module in Odoo, and everything seems to be ok. But when I try to install other modules I receive the next error:

Sorry, you are not allowed to access this document. Please contact your system administrator if you think this is an error.

(Document model: ir.module.module.exclusion) - (Operation: read, User: 2)

I no longer have rights to install new modules
What is causing that error?

Comment: Which module did you install? And what does the module do/change?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have the right to access to the records of the models, try adding your user to the user groups provided by the module that have the right to access (setting -> users and companies) or become superuser.

Answer (score 0):

`Administration / Settings` group users have all the permission (read, write, create, unlink) for `ir.module.module.exclusion` model. As you are trying to install apps, you are probably logged in as super user which has the group permission `Administration / Settings`. Probably the module you have installed is changing access right permission, you can look for `base.access_ir_module_module_exclusion_group_system` string in your custom modules code as that is the external id of the record for this particular model.

As per solution, you can go to Debug on `Settings > Technical > Models >  ir.module.module.exclusion`, in form view go to access rights tab, edit and set all permission for `Administration / Settings` to checked, as Jorge suggested in the previous answer.